# Yii Ignore Custom Field after Join

Tags: php, mysql, yii

When I add `$criteria->with=array('profile');` the field `revent_datetime` return NULL always,
but without `with` the `revent_datetime` return right.
Why with `with` criteria it happens?

Controller.php

```
public function actionIndex()
{
    $dayofweek = date('w');
    $criteria = new CDbCriteria;
    $criteria->select=array("
        CASE 
            WHEN weekday >= $dayofweek
            THEN CONCAT( DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL weekday - $dayofweek DAY), ' ', event_time )
            ELSE CONCAT( DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 7 - $dayofweek + weekday DAY), ' ', event_time )
        END as revent_datetime,

        CASE 
            WHEN weekday >= $dayofweek AND list_time IS NOT NULL
            THEN CONCAT( DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL weekday - $dayofweek DAY), ' ', list_time )
            ELSE CONCAT( DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 7 - $dayofweek + weekday DAY), ' ', list_time )
        END as rlist_datetime
    ");

    $criteria->with=array('profile'); // Thats the line w/ problem.

    $dataProvider=new CActiveDataProvider('Eventsreminder', array(
            'criteria' => $criteria
    ));

    $this->render('index',array(
        'dataProvider'=>$dataProvider,
    ));
}
```

---

Output:

```
$dataProvider->profile->name = Profile Test
$dataProvider->revent_datetime = NULL // here is the problem
$dataProvider->rlist_datetime = 2013-01-11 20:00:00
```

Comment: Please show your relation function of Eventsreminder's model, line where defined `profile`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, if you are use function in select you have to craete CDbExpression:

```
$criteria->select=array(
    new CDbExpression("CASE 
        WHEN weekday >= $dayofweek
        THEN CONCAT( DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL weekday - $dayofweek DAY), ' ', event_time )
        ELSE CONCAT( DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 7 - $dayofweek + weekday DAY), ' ', event_time )
    END as revent_datetime"),
    new CDbExpression("CASE 
        WHEN weekday >= $dayofweek AND list_time IS NOT NULL
        THEN CONCAT( DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL weekday - $dayofweek DAY), ' ', list_time )
        ELSE CONCAT( DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 7 - $dayofweek + weekday DAY), ' ', list_time )
    END as rlist_datetime")
);
```

Comment: As the 2 `CDbExpression` use the same `CASE` condition, can I mix them?

Comment: @LucianoNascimento, what do you mean `mix` ?

Comment: If is possible to Join the `CASEs` since the two use the same expression.

Comment: It's not same case, it's just like one to one, but use different fields: `event_time` and `list_time`